# Delete password-property in array to display the array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects where each object has an password. I want to display the array to the user but without the passwords, so I search for a method to delete the password-properties in all objects from the array.

My initial array is looking like this:

```js
[
   {
      Id: 'o-okmYvdl',
      Name: 'Test1',
      Password: '111'
   },
   {
      Id: 'o-fgnfgnh',
      Name: 'Test2',
      Password: '222'
   }
]
```

I want it to look like this:

```js
[
   {
      Id: 'o-okmYvdl',
      Name: 'Test1',
   },
   {
      Id: 'o-fgnfgnh',
      Name: 'Test2',
   }
]
```

Comment: Please refer to following pages when you are going to post a question:

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extended:** Now I make a copy from all properties of the Group-object except for the key 'Password', so the original array is unchanged and only the result is without the passwords.

```js
let Groups = [ { Id: 'o-okmYvdl', Name: 'Test1', Password: '111' }, { Id: 'o-fgnfgnh', Name: 'Test2', Password: '222' } ];

let result = Groups.map(el => {
    let obj = {};
    Object.entries(el).forEach(([key, val]) => {
        if (key!=='Password')
            obj[key] = val;
    })
    return obj;
});

console.log(result);
console.log((Groups));
```

Comment: I do not want to change the original array. I tested. In your answer, the password will be removed altogether

Sorry, My English is not as good as yours.

Comment: @DVOSTINA - I extended it for you, allthough your first task was to get the result in the Group-array. Now I create a copy of the objects just without the passwords.

Comment: @DVOSTINA - I answered your question some days ago. Your original array `Group`is after I extended the code unchanged (with the passwords) and the `result`-array is a copy of it just without the passwords. So you have both variants afterwards,

Comment: No, I asked a new question. sorry to bother you

Answer (score 0):

Is this code optimal?

```
var List = Groups.map(el => {
    let obj = {};
    Object.entries(el).forEach(([key, val]) => {

        if (key == 'Password') {

            obj["Lock"] = false;

            if (val) {

                obj["Lock"] = true;

            }

        }

        if (key === 'Members')
            obj["Value"] = val.length;

        if (key !== 'Password' && key !== 'CreatorId' && key !== 'Members')
            obj[key] = val;
    })
    return obj;
});

socket.emit("Receive_GetListGroup", { List });
```